# HDMI or ethernet over USB-C

Tags: hdmi, cable, usb-c

I'm running some cables through a small gap and would like to use low profile USB-C cables. I know you can get HDMI or ethernet adapters for USB, but I believe these are software based and require a driver. Can you get a device that simply maps the pins from one plug to the other?

E.g. could I go TV -> HDMI adapter -> USB-C cable -> HDMI adapter -> games console ?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: What signal do you actually want to transfer? Have you considered some sort of radio technology (e.g. WiFi) so that you don't have to get a physical cable through? Note that with a physical cable, the usual limiting factor is the size of the connectors.

Comment: USB has 24 pins, and HDMI has 19, so theoretically the answer is yes, you could do this. However, this would be a very niche product and it's more likely you could find actual slim HDMI cables (though, the lesser shielding in a slimmer cable would result in lower cable performance.

Comment: *speculation mode* You can get USB C fibre optic cables, so you could cut it and add fibre optic connectors to re-join it, but I don't know if the media convertors in the end connectors are tuned to the fibre, or if it's single-mode fibre then it might be cheaper to get someone else to add connectors for you rather than buy the necessary kit.

Comment: Do your devices even support video over USB Type-C?  If the devices on both ends do not support it, then running Type-C, won't really achieve anything except running cables you can't use.  Type-C also has a length consideration.

Comment: @Andrew you gave me an idea. After some googling, you can get hdmi cables with detachable ends (the cable they attach to is a "micro hdmi" cable.) Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @JoeS If you actually get it working, you can post it as an answer to your own question ;) I don't need the points or anything, and it's only a good answer if it is proven to work for you.

Comment: @music2myear Hrmm, that first sentence is deeply misleading. You can't just count conductors. You need to pay attention to twisted pairs, copper quality, crosstalk, frequency response, and several other factors. An extensive amount of signal quality engineering goes into the design of modern multi-gigabit cable designs.

Comment: @Spiff I chose not to engage in the complexity of cable design, leaving that for an eventual answer. I am aware that differences in cable design will result in differences in performance and can inhibit the function of one cable in the handling of a different cable's purpose.